# SQLAlchemy: add a child in many-to-many relationship by IDs

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am looking for a way to add a "Category" child to an "Object" entity without wasting the performance on loading the child objects first.

The "Object" and "Category" tables are linked with many-to-many relationship, stored in "ObjectCategory" table. The "Object" model is supplied with the relationsip:

```
categories = relationship('Category', secondary = 'ObjectCategory', backref = 'objects')
```

Now this code works just fine:

```
obj = models.Object.query.get(9)
cat1 = models.Category.query.get(22)
cat2 = models.Category.query.get(28)
obj.categories.extend([cat1, cat2])
```

But in the debug output I see that instantiating the obj and each category costs me a separate SELECT command to the db server, in addition to the single bulk INSERT command. Totally unneeded in this case, because I was not interested in manipulating the given category objects. Basically all I need is to nicely insert the appropriate category IDs.

The most obvious solution would be to go ahead and insert the entries in the association table directly:

```
db.session.add(models.ObjectCategory(oct_objID=9, oct_catID=22))
db.session.add(models.ObjectCategory(oct_objID=9, oct_catID=28))
```

But this approach is kind of ugly, it doesn't seem to use the power of the abstracted SQLAlchemy relationships. What's more it produces separate INSERT for every add(), vs the nice bulk INSERT as in the obj.categories.extend([list]) case. I imagine there could be some lazy object mode that would let the object live with only it's ID (unverified) and load the other fields only if they are requested. That would allow adding children in one-to-many or many-to-many relationships without issuing any SELECT to the database, yet letting to use the powerful ORM abstraction (ie, treating the list of children as a Python list).

How should I adjust my code to carry out this task using the power of SQLAlchemy but being conservative on the database use?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a ORM mapping for the ObjectCategory table? If so you could create and add ObjectCategory objects:

```
session.add(ObjectCategory(obj_id=9, category_id=22)
session.add(ObjectCategory(obj_id=9, category_id=28)
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer came exactly at the moment I was adding this approach to my post. It feels like passing the opportunity to use some nice relationships feature of SQLAlchemy properly. Besides, it produces series of INSERTs instead of single bulk INSERT.

Comment: Consider not worrying about the performance (at least not until you observe a problem). Could be that you're prematurely optimizing here?

Comment: I've experienced enough projects that heavily overuse the database to take your advice of "not worrying" with caution. In this particular case you're right, the cost is perhaps too negligent to justify hours of research&coding. But since I am rather new to SQLAlchemy and I plan to use it in large-scale projects, I want to learn the details of how it works and use it efficiently, instead of  sweeping the DB layer coding under the rug and wonder later why things get slower.

Comment: Good point. In SQLAlchemy, the key to performance is usually to know how to use the various eager loading techniques for relationships. And it is important to keep track of how many/what queries are executed. For instance in a web app, use some sort of "debug toolbar" that displays queries per request.

Comment: Exactly. Which leads back to what basically is my question - is there a way in SQLAlchemy to instantiate an object, using its primary key, lazily, so that the framework can carry out the child appending without bothering to load the objects from the database? Of course, thus the developer takes over the worry to verify that such ids actually exist in the database.

Comment: Well, that's not encouraging, but thanks for clarity.